# Fast method to cast [Float] to [CGFloat]?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, type-conversion

I'm having a brain cramp this afternoon.  This should be easy.

I did read the docs.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

It's easy to convert single instances of Float <> CGFloat but I'm looking for a fast method to cast a LARGE array > 500,000 elements of [Float] to [CGFloat].

```
var sphereRadiusFloat:[Float] = [0.0,1.0,2.0]
var sphereRadiusCGFloat:[CGFloat] = []

sphereRadiusCGFloat = sphereRadiusFloat as CGFloat
```

The error is

> CGFloat is not convertible to [CGFloat]

I also tried

```
sphereRadiusCGFloat = CGFloat(sphereRadiusFloat)
```

which gives error

> Could not find an overload operator for 'init' that accepts supplied
>   arguments.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to convert a type that is a array of CGFloat to just CGFloat, the method that @Leonardo Savio Dabus show you is a very elegant method new in swift, however the other way to do this would be looping all the elements in the array and converting one at the time

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid looping, and going the `Anyobject` route and like the map solution from @Leonardo Savio Dabus as it is `perl-ish`.  I'm a fan of those powerful one-liners.

Comment: Internally, of course, `map` is looping, you just don't see the loop explicitly.  It may be no faster.

Comment: i benchmarked a loop and map, for this particular call, the map vectorization is definitely faster by a substantial margin.  to the down voters, you know what you can do with your worthless opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use map to do it as follow:

```
sphereRadiusCGFloat = sphereRadiusFloat.map{CGFloat($0)}
```