# 'map' produces [T], not the expected contextual result type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>'

Tags: swift, cgfloat, unsafemutablepointer

I am calling `getLineDash` of a `UIBeizerPath` with this:

```
path.getLineDash(pattern.map{CGFloat($0)}, ...)
```

Where `pattern` is a `[Float]` (And I must use `[Float]`, not `[CGFloat]`) following [Fast method to cast [Float] to [CGFloat]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387085/fast-method-to-cast-float-to-cgfloat) to cast it to `[CGFloat]`, but it is giving me

```
Cannot convert value of type '[CGFloat]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?'
```

Weirdly, performing

```
path.setLineDash(pattern.map{CGFloat($0)}, ...
```

Does not raise a compile error.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686354/map-producing-t-in-swift-3-after-converting-from-swift-2) question, I added `as UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>` but it is still giving me the error.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515173/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-3

Comment: The method `setLineDash` takes `UnsafePointer<CGFloat>`, so you could use `map`. (Though, it is not an efficient way to call `map` at each invocation of `setLineDash`.) You **must** use `[CGFloat]` (or manually allocated region of `CGFloat`s) to call `getLineDash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit stupid. I didn't fully understand `UnsafeMutablePointer`s.

basically they are `inout` parameters, so they need the ampersand (`&`) before the function call. also, as it is inout, I must pass a variable of `[CGFloat]` to it.

This code worked:

```
var pat = pattern.map{CGFloat($0)}
var cou = count
var phas = phase.map{CGFloat($0)}
path.getLineDash(&pat, count: &cou, phase: &phas)
```